# Docker desktop takes forever to open

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, daemon, desktop

I just installed docker desktop, but when I try to run, I can only see the "Starting the docker engine" message.

This is the versions of my programs:

WSL: 1.2.5.0
kernel: 5.15.90.1
WSLg: 1.0.51
MSRDC: 1.2.3770
Direct3D: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows: 10.0.22621.1848

I really tryed everything, and I MUST be able to use docker on my pc, so please, help!

ps: It's the first time I use docker.

Thanks

I saw here on Stack Overflow someone with the same problem as me, and these are some tips which I tryed:

- Swich to windows containers -> It works, but for less than one minute, then the docker engine stops
- Containers, Hyper-v and windows subsystem for lynux are already on.
- Run the commands on powershell :
  wsl --unregister docker-desktop -> Nothing happens
  wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data -> Nothing happens
- Make shure that virtualization is ok on bios -> nothing happens
- Delete and install again docker - > Nothing happens